# Sorting in yii 1.1

Tags: yii

I have question regarding yii 1.1 sort.
I have three tables ticket, repairLogs and part table .
Following relations have been defined in Ticket model.

```
'repairLogs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'RepairLog', 'ticket_id', 'order'=>'ts DESC'),
```

and in repairLogs Table

```
'part' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Part', 'part_id'),
```

Part table has a column 'number' and I want to sort the data based on "number". Can anyone guide me how to do this since I am new to the yii 1.1 framework.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this during the `find()`

```
Ticket::model()->with(array('part', 'repairLogs'))->findAll(
    array(
        // your conditions here
        'order' => 'part.number DESC',   // "part" is the alias defined in your relation array (in the Ticket model file)
        'limit' => 10,
    )
);
```

If you are using A dataProvider, you can set it as a default order:

```
new CActiveDataProvider('Ticket', array(
    'criteria' => $criteria,    // you criteria that should include the "with" part
    'sort' => array(
        'defaultOrder' => 'part.number DESC',
    )
));
```

Comment: I tried this but it is showing below error :

CDbCommand failed to execute SQL expression: SQLSTATE [42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'part.number' in 'order clause'

Comment: you have to write the "with" part in you criteria:
```$criteria->with(array('part'));```